# MVC4 webservice error

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is the error:

> Cannot serialize member
>   baicadicungnamthang.Areas.admin.Models.Role.Users of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[baicadicungnamthang.Areas.admin.Models.User,
>   baicadicungnamthang, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.

The error occurred at the function getSong(int id) in the webservice.asmx file

Here is code in detail:

Role class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace baicadicungnamthang.Areas.admin.Models
{
    public class Role
    {
        [Key]
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

User class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using baicadicungnamthang.Areas.admin.Models.AlbumBase;
using baicadicungnamthang.Areas.admin.Models.Social;
using baicadicungnamthang.DAL;
using ICB;

namespace baicadicungnamthang.Areas.admin.Models
{
    public class User : Generic
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Song class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using baicadicungnamthang.Areas.admin.Models.Category;
using baicadicungnamthang.Areas.admin.Models.Person;
using baicadicungnamthang.DAL;

namespace baicadicungnamthang.Areas.admin.Models.SongBase
{
    public class Song : SongBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int SongID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Composer> Composers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

webservice.asmx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using baicadicungnamthang.Areas.admin.Models.SongBase;
using baicadicungnamthang.DAL;

namespace baicadicungnamthang
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for webservice
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://baicadicungnamthang.net/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class webservice : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        private baicadicungnamthangContext db = new baicadicungnamthangContext();

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public Song getSong(int id)
        {
            Song song = db.Songs.Find(id);
            return song;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize an interface. Answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659248/serializing-interfaces) question will explain you why.
Look at [this](http://www.johnsoer.com/blog/?tag=cannot-serialize-member-of-type-because-it-is-an-interface) as well.

Comment: I know that the reason is the model Role contains ICollection type of User that is an interface. But how the solution is? I can't change the type of member of a model (ICollection).